# How to Align Overlaying Elements

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have four elements at play: One gauge, and three text labels. I'm trying to horizontally align the text labels so that they are centered on the center of the gauge, however my current product looks like this:

[image]

The xaml for that block is as follows:

```
<Grid Margin="0 283 0 0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="83*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="149*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <lvc:Gauge x:Name="FreeSpaceGauge" Height="85" 
                   Uses360Mode="True"
                   From="0" To="100" Foreground="White"
                   HighFontSize="60" 
                   InnerRadius="70" GaugeActiveFill="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" Margin="-3,-31,3,33" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <lvc:Gauge.GaugeRenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"></RotateTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"></ScaleTransform>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </lvc:Gauge.GaugeRenderTransform>
                </lvc:Gauge>
                <TextBlock Name="FreeSpaceText" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="20" Width="Auto" Margin="10,-2,65,64" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Name="FreeSpaceText_Used" Text="USED" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Thin" FontSize="15" Width="Auto" Margin="12,24,63,38" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Name="FreeSpaceText_Available" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15" Width="Auto" Margin="70,84,50,-22" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            </Grid>
```

Any ideas as to how I can achieve the desired center alignment?

Answer (score 0):

It usually isn't a good choice to use static positioning (i.e. using `Margin`) of *WPF* elements, particularly if you want them to be centered (horizontally and/or vertically), because you need to know exact run-time position and size of the element in relation to which you're positioning your elements beforehand. Moreover, either that position and size need to be constant (which makes future adjustments a real pain), or you end up setting a bunch of ugly bindings.

Granted, sometimes it's inevitable, but luckily your particular goal is easily achievable with the right combination of containers (`Panel`s) and `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` values. I've ommitted properties which are not relevant in getting the desired layout and replaced your `Gauge` control with an `Ellipse` so that this code constitutes as much of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as possible:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Stroke="LightBlue" StrokeThickness="16" Width="100" Height="100" />
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="0%" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Text="USED" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="8 EB free" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
```

Here's how it looks in practice:

[image: Run-time snapshot]

Now let's break down the code. First we want two lines of text - one displaying a percentage, and another the string "USED", both centered horizontally, so we create two `TextBlock`s with `HorizontalAlignment="Center"`, and put them in a `StackPanel` in a top-to-down order, so that they are vertically stacked (`StackPanel` has `Orientation` property with default value of `Vertical`). We then want that part to be displayed over a gauge, vertically centered. So we put the gauge and the `StackPanel` in a `Grid` in a back-to-front order, and set `VerticalAlignment="Center"` on the `StackPanel` (note that we do not define any columns or rows). Lastly, we want some text below that part, so again we put that part and a `TextBlock` (with `HorizontalAlignment="Center"`) in a `StackPanel`, and voilà!

Now you can position the whole part by modifying only the outer `StackPanel` - again, advisably by setting alignment and using a right container, but you might as well use `Margin` property.

Answer (score 0):

Grx70 has posted a pretty good and small solution already. If you want to have a bit more control over how and where controls are placed, you can go a little deeper with nested grids.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="85" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border x:Name="FreeSpaceGauge" Height="85" Width="85" BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="15" CornerRadius="50" />

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Name="FreeSpaceText" Text="0%" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="20" Width="Auto" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock Name="FreeSpaceText_Used" Text="USED" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Thin" FontSize="15" Width="Auto" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>

    <TextBlock Name="FreeSpaceText_Available" Text="8 EB free" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

You are using a lot of unnecessary margins in your arrangment. That makes it difficult to arrange this controls.